# tomcat starts on shell but i cant get nto the browser with localhost:8080?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, raspberry-pi2, catalina

I have a serious problems with  installing tomcat on  **rapsberry pi**

I did the following

1. Downloaded the source
2. Added the user `raspberry` in `tomcat-users.xml`
3. Exectued the startup.sh

In the shell it says that tomcat started but when I am trying to open it in browser I am getting an error.
In the log file it says :

```
./catalina.sh : 1: eval :usr/lib/jvm/jsk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/bin/java : not found
```

But the file  exsists  in the corresponded path !! what to do am stuck since  the afternoon in it   :(

Comment: Whats striking to me is that the path that has been output lacks the leading slash, when you check you may infer that it starts at `/` but the lacking slash may still be the problem. You may examine the `catalina.sh`, check where the JRE paths comes from and why there's a slash missing.

Comment: i checked  it even  twice but still  the same problem i ma dying  here !!

Comment: Improved the question, corrected the spelling and format

Comment: thanks man forgive myy spelling ..i m despered i need it done for tonight so ican deploy my web app asap

Answer (score 0):

Just executing `startup.sh` does not necessarily start tomcat. It just delegates the start process to the background - and if that succeeds, `startup.sh` terminates and displays success.

Here's what you can do to determine what the root issue is:

- start tomcat with `catalina.sh run` - this will start tomcat with all log output in the foreground and you'll see the problem immediately, not just when inspecting the log file
- As try-catch-finally mentions in a comment: The path to your java executable lacks a leading slash - you might have a wrong JAVA_HOME configuration set (indicating a relative path instead of an absolute one
- If you have a `tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` file, post it here. If you don't have it: Add it (and make it executable with this one line to check the JAVA_HOME suggestion from try-catch-finally:

  JAVA_HOME=/${JAVA_HOME}

(this is a temporary workaround for testing the condition mentioned. If it succeeds, you should fix your JAVA_HOME, whereever you set it)